# I type vi ~/.bashrc but I get -bash: vi: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, directory

I type `vi ~/.bashrc` but I get

```
-bash: vi: No such file or directory
```

What might be the problem? Sorry, this is something new for me.

Comment: Please don't cross post on sites.

Comment: What's the output of `which vi` and `apt-cache policy vim vim.tiny`?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Ubuntu? (mobaxterm

Answer (score 2):

**1. Problem:**

If when you type:

```
echo $PATH
```

you get *no* result your `$PATH` statement is a little awry. On a fresh install of Xenial you *should* see the following:

```
andrew@athens:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
andrew@athens:~$
```

This is set on a *system* level in `/etc/environment` where you will see the following:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

The extra `snap` entry in my `$PATH` statement is found in `/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh` where you will see the entry:

```
# Expand the $PATH to include /snap/bin which is what snappy applications
# use
PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin
```

**2. Solution:**

Rather than tamper with these *system* files perhaps safest is to add the following to a local file: `~/.profile`, adding the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

and then run: `source ~/.profile` or simply log out and back in. Then your system should be able to find `vim` easily enough....